# What is the fastest way to combine 8 uint8_t into a single uintmax_t?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, bit-manipulation, uint8t

I am looking to optimize a piece of code that uses `popcnt` to compute differences between `uint8_t`s.  I figure it'd be faster to combine 8 `uint8_t`s into a single `uintmax_t` and use `popcnt64` instead so that the popcnt operation doesn't have to be called 8x more than necessary.  What is the fastest way to feed 8 `uint8_t` into `popcnt64`?  Can I use some kind of casting?  Should I make use of bit manipulation?  I'm not aware of C++'s internal workings so I'm not sure what the fastest way is to make this conversion.

Comment: For an 8-bit type, the fastest way to count bits is to use a lookup table. It would have 256 entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't care about endianness – you just want to treat the `uint8_t`s as a `uint64_t` and you don't care about the order of the `uint8_t`s – then you can just use [`std::memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) to do the type punning:

```
std::uint64_t combine(std::array<std::uint8_t, 8> b) {
    static_assert(sizeof(b) == sizeof(std::uint64_t));
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<std::uint64_t>);
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<decltype(b)>);

    std::uint64_t result;
    std::memcpy(&result, b.data(), sizeof(result));
    return result;
}
```

The [generated assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/pA446r) just returns the argument:

```
combine(std::array<unsigned char, 8ul>): # @combine(std::array<unsigned char, 8ul>)
  mov rax, rdi
  ret
```

Using anything else for type punning makes it so you have to worry about *strict aliasing* rules or alignments of types. It's easy enough to just use `std::memcpy` and let the compiler deal with it

---

Note that the easiest way of calling any variant of `popcnt` from C++ is to use [`std::bitset::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/count). So instead of `__builtin_popcountll(my_u64)` or `__popcnt64(my_u64)`, you could just write `std::bitset<64>{my_u64}.count()` and you instantly get portable code.